# What is the scope of rake in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am very new to ruby on rails. What is the function of `rake`. For example here one command like

```
rake db:create
```

Here this command which is used to create the new database. But before we use `rake`. Why we use `rake` word here, what it is function.

And what is the different between `rake` `rake-task` & `rakefile`.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

[Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) is a Ruby build command. When you invoke `rake`, you are actually using the Rake tool and you ask Rake to read and use the `Rakefile` available in your Rails application folder.

Rake is used to automate several tasks, from the creation of a database, to a database migration, to the generation of new models or controllers.

I encourage you to read [this article about Rake](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html) to learn more about this tool. It will be one of the fundamental tools you'll use working with Rails, so you really need to understand what it is before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Rake is a gem that acts like make in the *nix world. You use it to run scripts, usually the `Rakefile`. You use it to run tests or set up databases. Rails uses it extensively because there are many steps that need to be run between deployments.

Rake can do pretty much anything you need to automate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wikipedia article on it that is a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_(software)

The main thing it does, really, is to be a central point for command-line tasks for the application. You don't really need it for half the things it's used for (and quite frequently isn't the best IMO), but by running `rake -D` you'll get a list of all the commands available, which is helpful.